# Неправильно отрабатывает RULE insert в PosrtgreSql 9.5/9.6

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пример

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
id bigserial NOT NULL,
name text
);


ALTER TABLE public.test
ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id);


CREATE TABLE public.v_test
(
id bigserial NOT NULL,
v_id bigint,
v_name text
);


ALTER TABLE public.v_test
ADD CONSTRAINT v_test_constraint_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id);


CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert AS
ON INSERT TO test DO INSERT INTO v_test (v_id, v_name)
VALUES (new.id, new.name);
```

После выполняю

```
insert into test(name)
values 
('1'),
('2'),
('3')
```

значения в  test.id не сходятся с v_test.v_id

postgresql 9.5/9.6 ставлю из PPA

ОС ubuntu-sever 14.04/16.04

Comment: Возможно, v_test.id нужно сделать bigint, а не bigserial?

Comment: Вы не поняли, правило записывает поле test.id в v_test.v_id. и записывает неправильно

Comment: Я как раз правильно понял. Зачем использовать serial, если все равно пишется определенный bigint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения не сходятся очень интересным образом, а именно - использованы следующие `nextval`. Если id в insert задать явно - rule копирует данные нормально. Видимо, в этом и проблема, второй `insert` получает дефолтное значение колонки ещё раз.

Похоже, так система rule и [работает изначально](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/361.1126880591%40sss.pgh.pa.us).

Экспериментируем,

```
create function testnotice() 
returns bigint as 
$$ 
begin 
    raise notice 'executed';
    return 1;
end 
$$ language plpgsql;

alter table test add column tescolumn bigint default testnotice();

alter table v_test add column tescolumn bigint;

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE insert AS
ON INSERT TO test DO INSERT INTO v_test (v_id, v_name, tescolumn)
VALUES (new.id, new.name, new.tescolumn);
```

пробуем что-нибудь записать:

```
melkij=# insert into test(name) values ('6');
NOTICE:  executed
NOTICE:  executed
INSERT 0 1
```

Так и есть, функция для default поля вызвана дважды. serial/bigserial, которые на самом деле макрос для `default nextval(sequencename)`, поэтому тоже вызываются дважды.

В качестве `new.*` подставляются не значения из результата какого-то запроса, а непосредственно объявление колонок: явно указанные в запросе insert либо default значения.

Используйте вместо этого `after insert` триггер. Он будет иметь ожидаемое поведение и в NEW предоставит именно значения уже записанной строки.

Comment: А может есть возможность работать с RULE без повторного вызова nextval ?

Comment: Мне не известно такого.